# La différence entre obligatoire et obligé

Tags: choix-de-mot

Qu'est-ce que c'est la différence entre obligatoire et obligé? J'ai regardé certains exemples mais je ne peux pas les distinguer.

Comment: « Qu'est-ce que la différence » ou « Qu'est-ce que c'est que la différence » — mais non « Qu'est-ce que c'est la différence ».

Comment: Encore mieux: "quelle est la différence entre X et Y" .

Comment: @LukeSawczak *Qu'est-ce que c'est, la différence entre...* can be heard in colloquial spoken French, but is indeed unexpected in written form.

Comment: @Greg & jlliagre both true

Answer (score 6):

Dans la langue courante, écrite et parlée, « obligatoire » est un adjectif et « obligé » surtout un participe passé, c'est à dire qu'il s'emploie avec un auxiliaire verbal ; « obligatoire » implique une obligation sur le plan des lois à divers niveaux : lois de l'état, règles au sein de diverses institutions, règles dans certains systèmes comme par exemple la grammaire, etc.

- Il est obligatoire d'avoir dix-huit ans pour voter.
- Il est obligatoire de porter un tablier dans cet établissement scolaire.
- Dans cette construction grammaticale il est obligatoire de placer le complément d'attribution avant le complément d'objet direct.

« obligé » implique une contrainte plus ou moins spécifique selon le domaine auquel le mot est appliqué; par exemple dans les trois exemples qui précèdent, les obligations légales, règles institutionnelles et systématiques entrainent une contrainte et pour chacun des contextes utilisés on peut exprimer en plus les idées suivantes (toutes similaires entre elles);

- Vous êtes obligé d'avoir dix-huit ans pour voter. Dans cet établissement les élèves sont obligés de porter un tablier. Dans cette construction vous êtes obligé de placer le complément…

On ne choisit pas de spécifier la nature de la contrainte.

Un autre domaine d'obligations plus ou moins contraignantes est celui des obligations morales;

- Vous êtes obligé de répondre au gens qui vous adressent la parole.
- Un chrétien est obligé en vertu de ses croyances de soulager s'il le peut la souffrance de personnes dans une misère extrême.
- Un invité à une cérémonie est obligé de prévenir de son absence s'il ne peut pas y assister.

Un troisième domaine de contraintes est celui des contraintes matérielles.

- Lorsque le vent est trop fort les marins sont obligés de diminuer la voilure.
- Les travailleurs viticoles sont obligés de mettre des bottes lorsqu'il pleut et qu'ils ont à marcher entre les rangs de vigne.

L'essentiel de l'utilisation du participe passé a été passé en revue. En ce qui concerne l'adjectif, l'emploi est différent.

1 - D'abord on ne l'utilise pas couramment dans la langue parlée; un niveau de langue élevé est nécessaire et aussi, parfois en même temps, un sujet spécialisé;

2 - On ne trouve plus la même idée de contrainte dans l'adjectif mais dans chaque cas particulier une nuance de cette idée.

- prévisible et inévitable : Le contribuable paiera, c'est obligé. (*Fam.*)
- qui est d'usage : Dans ces petites cartes postales on trouve souvent l'image d'une Tour Eiffel, c'est le symbole obligé pour ces souvenirs touristiques.

En plus des quatre cas importants donnés en exemple il en existe d'autres beaucoup plus spécialisés et il vaut mieux consulter un dictionnaire lorsque ces rares cas posent un problème de compréhension.

On peut mentionner l'usage substantif suivant de la forme, lequel ajoute à l'idée de plusieurs nuances qui viennent se greffer sur le concept de contrainte. C'est cependant un usage réservé à un assez haut registre de langue, possiblement seulement littéraire, mais il n'y a pas cette stipulation dans le TLFi.

obligé : personne qui est redevable à quelqu'un en raison d'un service

exemples tirés du TLFi:

> Je voulais des obligés et non pas des lecteurs. Sartre, 1964, Mots
>
> De ce jour où je cessai d'être votre obligé, je devins votre enthousiaste… (DUMAS père, Napoléon)

Comment: Très bonne réponse. J'ajouterais qu'il est obligatoire de mettre un trait d'union à *dix-huit*. Par ailleurs, on pourrait mentionner l'usage désuet dans *je suis votre obligé*, et l'expression courante mais incorrecte *c'est obligé*.

Comment: @chqrlie 1) D'après le TLFi « c'est obligé », si on parle bien de la même expression, ne serait que familier : Fam. C'est/c'était obligé. C'est/c'était une chose inévitable. Synon. c'est forcé*, fatal*. 2) *Je/nous…suis/sommes…votre obligé* serait probablement désuet dans la langue parlée mais je ne suis pas sûr que ce soit le cas dans la langue écrite comme il le TLFi ne mentionne rien à ce sujet; de plus il ne s'agit pas d'une expression figée mais seulement d'un substantif que l'on trouve dans Dumas et plus récemment dans Sartre.

Comment: @chqrlie Oui, attention à ne pas confondre niveau de langue et correction. "C'est obligé" est une expression correcte et de registre familier.

Answer (score 3):

Ce qui est obligatoire, vous devez le faire. Dans ce cas, c'est vous qui êtes obligé.

Comparez :

> As-tu fait le devoir pour demain ?
>
> Oui, c'était obligatoire.

Vs. :

> Vas-tu aller à la fête du marquis ?
>
> Oui, je suis obligé.

Notez que *obligé* est aussi le participe passé de *obliger*.